# xcode/interface builder linking to page

Tags: xcode

Hi all
I am a newby app developer infact I am still in high school, I am making a radio app and I have made the channel list using interface builder (mainwindow.xib in xcode) now I want to be able to click on a link/button in the main window and that take me too a new page in the app where I can have a play button and maybe a symbol etc. I know it is probably a trivial question but I am stumped, but how do I go about doing this if someone could place it out in step by step or even a few screenshots it really would be apreciated?
Many Thanks in advance
David

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you want to be able to use a UIButton to take you to an entirely new view controller? Well, for your particular case, I'd recommend trying a Tab bar controller. When you create a new application, it gives you an option for what type of template you want, and Tab bar controller is one of them. This creates a black bar across the bottom that lets you cycle between several different independent view controllers. Just create a new tab bar application, and copy/paste your existing code into one of the views, then use the other one(s) to do whatever else you have in mind. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi if I understand you you are saying there are only two windows, Now with my app there will probably be around 6 buttons in the main windows which I want to individually be able to press to take me to its own window. with a start/play/listen/stop button etc. is this possible I saw someone one youtube "making radio app" and he linked it somehow by draging some blue line acroos, I am sorry if I am not too clear, if anyone can help I would greatly apreciate it.

Comment: Actually, with tab bar you can go up to 5 windows easily before it starts to appear cluttered. You'll be a bit restricted in how you arrange the interface, but it isn't too bad, just arrange one tab bar button as play, the next as listen, the next as stop, etc. If you need more windows for your app, then I'd recommend switching to a navigation controller, but those are a bit more complicated.

Comment: Hi If I understand you tab bar would be across the bottom and there would be a button for start srop etc, I would like to be able to have the buttons in each window as they are web based buttons with data, I would also like something like navigatation controller where everything has its own page. Is this possible and how do I link the pages, If you know of any really simplistic how to sites I really would apreciate it. Thanks David

Comment: Well, I learned my objecive C from here: http://www.lynda.com/tutorial/48369, but since you have to pay for that site it might not be what you're looking for.